# C# ASP.NET MVC view data not being sent back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form within a view with code that looks like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Summary", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
 {
 <div class="row">
      <label for="Election[1].percent" class="col-sm-9 col-form-label text-left">text line 1</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
           <input type="number" class="form-control election" id="Election[1].percent" min="0" max="100" value="0">
           <input type="number" hidden id="Election[1].fund" value="1" />
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
      <label for="Election[2].percent" class="col-sm-9 col-form-label text-left">text line 2</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
           <input type="number" class="form-control election" id="Election[2].percent" min="0" max="100" value="0">
           <input type="number" hidden id="Election[2].fund" value="1" />
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
      <label for="Election[3].percent" class="col-sm-9 col-form-label text-left">text line 3</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
           <input type="number" class="form-control election" id="Election[3].percent" min="0" max="100" value="0">
           <input type="number" hidden id="Election[3].fund" value="1" />
      </div>
 </div>
 }
```

The above is generated in the view based on data being passed in the model.  There can be up to 100 rows being generated.  As you can see, in each iteration, the subscript of Election increases by 1.

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public class FundElection
{
    public int percent { get; set; }
    public int fund { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller, I have this code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Summary(List<FundElection> formData)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

The submit button is disabled by default on the form and there is jQuery code in the view which totals the user entered percents as the user enters them. Once the total of all percents is 100, the submit button becomes enabled.

This is the code that runs to do that:

```
$(function () {

    $('.election').change(function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $('.election').each(function () {
            sum += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        var totalElection = sum + "%";
        $("#ElectionTotal").text(totalElection)
        if (sum == 100) {
            $("#submitButton").prop("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $("#submitButton").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    })

});
```

When I set a breakpoint on the return View() and run the application, the view gets generated correctly.  When I click on the submit button (once the percents entered total 100) the form gets submitted but the breakpoint is never hit. In fact, when using Chrome, Chrome reports there is a problem with the page `/ControllerName/Summary` and when I test with Safari, I just get a blank page.

Any idea where the form went?

Thanks.

Edited:
Here is an image from the Network tab that shows the bottom few elements on the form and the error that is being reported.

[image]

Edit 2:

I changed the form in the view from POST to GET so I could see the data and I changed the action method in the controller from `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpGet]`.

This is what is being passed;

> https://localhost:5001/OnlineEnrollment/Summary?Election%5B1%5D.percent=0&Election%5B1%5D.fund=1&Election%5B2%5D.percent=0&Election%5B2%5D.fund=2&Election%5B3%5D.percent=0&Election%5B3%5D.fund=3&Election%5B4%5D.percent=0&Election%5B4%5D.fund=4&Election%5B5%5D.percent=0&Election%5B5%5D.fund=5&Election%5B6%5D.percent=0&Election%5B6%5D.fund=6&Election%5B7%5D.percent=0&Election%5B7%5D.fund=7&Election%5B8%5D.percent=0&Election%5B8%5D.fund=8&Election%5B9%5D.percent=0&Election%5B9%5D.fund=9&Election%5B10%5D.percent=0&Election%5B10%5D.fund=10&Election%5B11%5D.percent=0&Election%5B11%5D.fund=11&Election%5B13%5D.percent=0&Election%5B13%5D.fund=13&Election%5B14%5D.percent=0&Election%5B14%5D.fund=14&Election%5B15%5D.percent=0&Election%5B15%5D.fund=15&Election%5B16%5D.percent=0&Election%5B16%5D.fund=16&Election%5B17%5D.percent=0&Election%5B17%5D.fund=17&Election%5B18%5D.percent=0&Election%5B18%5D.fund=18&Election%5B19%5D.percent=0&Election%5B19%5D.fund=19&Election%5B22%5D.percent=0&Election%5B22%5D.fund=22&Election%5B23%5D.percent=0&Election%5B23%5D.fund=23&Election%5B24%5D.percent=0&Election%5B24%5D.fund=24&Election%5B25%5D.percent=0&Election%5B25%5D.fund=25&Election%5B26%5D.percent=0&Election%5B26%5D.fund=26&Election%5B27%5D.percent=0&Election%5B27%5D.fund=27&Election%5B28%5D.percent=0&Election%5B28%5D.fund=28&Election%5B29%5D.percent=0&Election%5B29%5D.fund=29&Election%5B30%5D.percent=0&Election%5B30%5D.fund=30&Election%5B31%5D.percent=0&Election%5B31%5D.fund=31&Election%5B32%5D.percent=0&Election%5B32%5D.fund=32&Election%5B33%5D.percent=0&Election%5B33%5D.fund=33&Election%5B34%5D.percent=0&Election%5B34%5D.fund=34&Election%5B35%5D.percent=0&Election%5B35%5D.fund=35&Election%5B36%5D.percent=0&Election%5B36%5D.fund=36&Election%5B37%5D.percent=075&Election%5B37%5D.fund=37&Election%5B40%5D.percent=25&Election%5B40%5D.fund=40

Is it possible that the naming convention is causing this issue?

Comment: *"Chrome reports there is a problem with the page"* - What is that problem?  Are you getting an error response back from the server?  An HTTP 500 response code?

Comment: At a glance... None of these `<input>` elements have `name` attributes, so none of them would be sending any values in the form POST.

Comment: Is your controller name really ControllerName?

Comment: @David Its returning an http error 431 - request header fields too large.  Maybe I should change the View from submitting the form to sending an ajax request to the controller?

Comment: @JonathanSmall: I'm surprised anything is being sent to the server at all since there are no `name` attributes on the form elements.  And the *header* is too large?  Check the network tab of the browser's debugging tools to see what's being sent in the request.  Does anything stand out as being too large?  If the fields are sent in a POST body then there shouldn't be a meaningful limit.

Comment: @David I'm surprised as well.  Looking at the network tab, I dont see anything out of the norm.  It shows a list of all the elements on the form along with their values.  I have taken a screen shot and added it to original post.  Could it have something to do with the __RequestVerificationToken element?  I dont know what that is.

Comment: @JonathanSmall: That looks like just an XSS token built-in to the framework.  I'm still pretty surprised that data is sent at all without `name` attributes, but I suppose the framework may be adding those automatically now?  Seems like an invitation for problems as soon as someone doesn't use this framework.  Either way... How about the Headers tab in the request?  Any excessive request headers?  Overall, what's the size of the total request? If it *is* the request body producing the error then my next suggestion would be to split it up into multiple requests somehow, which may be a UX change.

Comment: @David I dont see anything strange on the header tab.  the data that I am passing is really small.  In this case, its 40 elements, each element has 2 parts with each part having no more than 3 bytes each.  Thats only 240 bytes total.